# How to disable enter keypress event in Textbox in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view like this

```
<input id = "txtQty" type = "text" value = "<%= Model.Qty %> class = "qtyTxt" onfocus = "$('#oldValue').val(this.value)" onchange = "updateQty("<%= Model.Id %>, this.value %>)" />

...
<button class = "ui-button" onclick="deleteItem(<%=Model.Id)"> Remove </button>
```

Javascript

```
function updateQty(id, qty)
{
  //...
}

function deleteItem(id)
{
  //...
}
```

Now, my problem is whenever I enter value in the textbox and press enter key it called both method one after another in js. Mouse click is working fine but enter keypress is not working as I expected. I need to call only `updateQty` method when I press enter key. How can I achieve this?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery like this:

```
$('txtQty').keypress(function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      //call method here
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I didn't understand  `call method here` what do you mean by that? If I have to call my method with parameter how can I do that?

Comment: That's where you'll call your `updateQty` function. You can pass in your parameters like `updateQty('@Model.ID', this.value)`